# loop in my form login using a costom user provider

Tags: symfony, authentication

I am a notice in symfony, I have problem with my authentification , I search every solution , any work for me

I am stuck in my form login :
this is my security.yml

```
encoders:
    UserBundle\Security\User: bcrypt
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_AGENT:       ROLE_USER
providers:
    user_provider:
        id: user.user_provider
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/agent, role: ROLE_AGENT }
firewalls:
    login_firewall:
        pattern:   ^/login$
        anonymous: ~
    agent_firewall:
        pattern: ^/agent
        provider: user_provider
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
            login_path: login_agent
            check_path: login_agent
        logout:
            path:   /logout
            target: /login
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    main:
        anonymous: ~
```

my services.yml

```
user.user_provider:
    class: UserBundle\Security\UserProvider
    arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager']
```

my login.html.twig

```
<form action="{{ path('login_agent') }}" method="post">
    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" />

    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" />

    {#
        If you want to control the URL the user
        is redirected to on success (more details below)
        <input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="/account" />
    #}

    <button type="submit">login</button>
</form>
```

my route login :

```
/**
 * @Route("/login_agent", name="login_agent")
 */
public function loginAction(Request $request)
{
    $authenticationUtils = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');

    // get the login error if there is one
    $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

    // last username entered by the user
    $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

    return $this->render('AppBundle::login.html.twig', array(
        'last_username' => $lastUsername,
        'error'         => $error,
    ));
}
```

I hope that someone can help me, Im blocked , I dont know what can I do more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set you `login_path` to `/login` or similar (and not to the same as the `check_path`) and change you `loginAction` accordingly.

Symfony directly intersect when you are POSTing stuff to the `check_path` and will relink to your `login_path` if the authentication was not successful (where you then can check for errors)

Relevant docs: http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/custom_password_authenticator.html. I can also recommend taking a look at the `FOSUserBundle` to see how they have solved this: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Controller/SecurityController.php. Relevant code below:

```
class SecurityController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * the login path /login
     */
    public function loginAction(Request $request)
    {
        $session = $request->getSession();
        //checking errors & setting variables

        return $this->render('@FOSUser/Security/login.html.twig', array(
            'last_username' => $lastUsername,
            'error' => $error,
            'csrf_token' => $csrfToken,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * the check path /login_check
     */
    public function checkAction()
    {
        throw new \RuntimeException('You must configure the check path to be handled by the firewall using form_login in your security firewall configuration.');
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried the solution , but didn't work

I added :

    /**

 * @Route("/agent/login_check", name="login_check")
 */
public function checkAction()
{
    throw new \RuntimeException('You must configure the check path to be handled by the firewall using form_login in your security firewall configuration.');
}

And in my security.yml :

            form_login:
            login_path: /login_agent
            check_path: /agent/login_check

Comment: Please check that in `login_agent` (with your login form) you are indeed submitting to the check path (so `/agent/login_check`). If this is the case, try to explain what exactly did not work

Comment: think you for your help, it's work for me, what i didn't do earlier, it's to change my path in action form login :
action="{{ path('login_check') }}"